# Android USB OTG Device : How to turn off USB OTG Device connected to android phone

Tags: android, usb, android-audiomanager, usb-otg

I am working on an application which makes use of OTG Sleeve(device) as an audio source. But the problem is that the OTG device does not have a de-echoing chip integrated to it. So, an echo is heard whenever a phone call is made.
Is there any way to stop OTG device from being an audio source or turn off the usb device programmatically from the app during the phone call?
I am looking for a way for the android application to disable the usb otg device.